# List From Dynamic Row & Column (2 dimentional)- Xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("adsd.xlsx") 
sht = wb.sheets["test"]

lrow = sht.range('A7').end('down')
lcol = sht.range('zz7').end('left')
```

a = A7:Z70 list

Is that possible to create a list from a7: last col and last row?

Thank you

For example if lrow: 70, lcol: Z

A will be a7:Z70

Comment: To create a list of the range `new_list = sht['A7:Z70'].value` See [Xlwings Lists](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists) for more detail.

Comment: yes, is that possible to make it dynamic? because every time the row and column will be different

Comment: You can use an `f-string` to place the `column` and/or `row` `co-ordinates` in the range; example:- `sht[f'{scol}{srow}:{ecol}{erow}'].value` where `scol` is `start column` e.g. `'A'` and `ecol` is `end column` e.g. `'Z'` & `srow & erow` are the `row numbers`. Or the variables can be the combined so `sht[f'{start_coord}:{end_coord}']` etc